# Get a SAML2 Token from ADFS in Java

Tags: java, saml-2.0, opensaml

currently I am trying to connect to a REST Webservice (https) from a Java Application. It took me a while to figure out that the only way to call the Webservice is with an SAML2 authentication. I have the user credentials (name + pwd) and the connection should be done in background, the user should not notice the process.
To be precise: 
At first I have to contact the ADFS to authenticate and get a SAML2 Token. 
Second I can contact the Webservice and add the SAML2 Token.

Now I am wondering how to achieve this. Especially contacting the ADFS is where I am stuck right now. I guess it could be done with opensaml but during the research i didn't find a solution. 
Can anybody give me a simple example how to get a SAML2 Token?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS server is also a SecurityTokenService (STS), and your java program can use WS-Trust client to request SAML token from ADFS by exchanging WS-Security UsernameToken.
For WS-Trust questions, see http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/ws-trust-1.3-os.html